# Required visa type for Interview: Germany

Tags: germany, schengen, interview

Currently, I am being interviewed by a German firm and they want me to be in Germany for the remaining rounds, for three days. Since there is no formal `interview visa` category so which is the best visa type way forward to visit Germany?

Current passport: `Indian`
Current location: `Bangalore`
Location visiting in Germany: `Munich`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably be a visitor visa, since you will submitting documentation from the employer about the steps needed to compleate the job interview process.

What they will exactly write in the comments field is hard to say, but in some form it will express the purpose of the visit.